# How to grab checkbox value as integer and not string mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a checkbox on View

```
<label>IsGym</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="IsGym" name="IsGym" value="1" />
```

And on controller

```
public string GetVendorLocation(string IsGym)
{}
```

But i do not want checkbox value to come in string. I want the value of checkbox to be in integer

In my model also i defined `IsGym` as `int`
but as soon as i write `int IsGym` in controller, the class is not hit.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes do not post a value so if you leave it unchecked, you may get an error if the property is `int IsGym`. Change it to `int? IsGym` (nullable).  But why is a property named `IsGym` an `int` when the naming suggests it should be a `bool`?

Comment: Because the SP which I am using has defines IsGym has int and i do not have authority to change that

Comment: You can pass value to SP as int. In controller just check if it is true send 1 otherwise send 0.

Comment: Thank You very much. Really appreaciated the help